# Expand {...} in IE developer console

Tags: javascript, object, internet-explorer-8

When I use the javascript console in I.E -8 for some cross browser testing and bug fixing, and try to view an object in it's expanded form (like the one that comes up in Chrome dev console) - it simply gives a {...} - How to make I.E 8 always expand the key value pairs when using the developer console to view object properties.

Snapshot: https://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/Z68S

Comment: If you want to have an initially expanded log, try `console.dir` instead

Comment: clicking doesnt help.. the I.E dev console that im using is divided into 2 parts, below a single line to enter commands etc and then a top display pane to see the results (not like chrome's) - so when the result is an object /array it never expands- just displays static text {...} in the display pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in the day, I have struggled with IE's "[object Object]" logs. I used one of these approaches:

- switch to debug mode (`Script` tab > `Start Debugging`), add breakpoints and watch variables (`Watch` tab on the right) as they change
- use `JSON.stringify` to get a full-text representation of your objects. For improved readability try: `JSON.stringify(data, null, "\t")`

Lastly, you have my sympathies for having to develop for IE 8 :)

Comment: haha... that last line was from fb right?? 
Will try out this approach, Thanks!!

Comment: @Prabhas: No, those were my sincere feelings!